# NextJS/React clock changes position on rerenders

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a clock widget in NextJS which uses SVG since it needs to be scalable to very large screens and I have the clock widget ready but I want it to be centered and stay in the same place, but right now it repositions itself a little to the left or a little to the right every second because the width of the numbers isn't always the same. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
// ** React Imports
import {ReactNode, useEffect, useState} from 'react'

// ** MUI Components
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'

// ** Layout Import
import BlankLayout from 'src/@core/layouts/BlankLayout'

// ** Library Import
import moment from 'moment'

interface PersonalizedClockProps {
  darkMode: boolean
  showSeconds: boolean
}

const PersonalizedClockStyled = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'block',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  height: '100vh',
  width: '100vw',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  '& svg': {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  '& #time': {
    fontSize: '9rem',
    fontWeight: 500
  }
}))


const PersonalizedClock = (props: PersonalizedClockProps) => {
  const { darkMode, showSeconds } = props;
  // const format = showSeconds ? 'HH:mm:ss' : 'HH:mm';
  const format = 'HH:mm:ss';
  const [time, setTime] = useState(moment().format(format));

  // needs to update every second
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(moment().format(format));
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [format]);

  return (
    <PersonalizedClockStyled>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 560 300">
          <text id="time" x="50%" y="50%" className="classes.text" textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="central">
            {time}
          </text>
        </svg>
    </PersonalizedClockStyled>
  );
}

PersonalizedClock.getLayout = (page: ReactNode) => <BlankLayout>{page}</BlankLayout>

export default PersonalizedClock;
```

I have already tried to change the positioning to be absolute, and tried to add an outside div that has the absolute positioning but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to use a fixed-width/monospace font.
https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace